# How to select database query in this case?

Tags: php, sql, database, logic

Hi I am running into a unique problem. I have database structure of sales order and comparision tables like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEW3L.png)

[image]

There will be more records in comparision table. 
Basically I want to get the result like the pictures belows. Note: the AFFID can be any random number.

[image]

I haven't be able to think of a good way to call SQL. I feel like I have to call SQL then create a new Array that has structure

```
[
'campaign_left',
'campaign_right'
'Comparision_id'
]
```

to be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can get the answer by doing this :

step 1 : get the uniqueAFFIDS array = [1020,1040,1028]
step 2 : sort the uniqueAFFIDS array = [ 1020,1028,1040]

```
ForEach Comparisions as Comparision 
------ ForEach uniqueAFFIDS as uniqueAFFID
------------- $total left = Select Where campaign_id = comparision->campaign_id-left && affid = uniqueAFFID ; 
------------- $total right = Select Where campaign_id = comparision->campaign_id-right && affid = uniqueAFFID ;
```

Then i just display it.

I wonder if anyone has good idea other that this.

Thanks.